# import lightgbm returned non-zero exit status 2

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, lightgbm

I am running Windows 10. Today I installed `lightgbm` through anaconda using

`conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`

However, when I tried to import lightgbm (running Jupyter Notebook), I got the following error trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5dacb4a27011> in <module>
----> 1 import lightgbm as lgb

D:\RI\0Teaching Materials\QTDM-II\P30 LGBM\lightgbm.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from subprocess import check_output
---> 12 print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
     13 
     14 # Any results you write to the current directory are saved as output.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    334 
    335     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 336                **kwargs).stdout
    337 
    338 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    416         if check and retcode:
    417             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 418                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    419     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    420 

CalledProcessError:Command '['ls', '../input']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

What is preventing me from importing `lightgbm`?

Update:- Thinking that this is a Windows issue, I installed Anaconda on Ubuntu (Oracle VB) and tried import. Unfortunately, same error occurred in this environment too. What could be behind this?

Comment: "D:\RI\0Teaching Materials\QTDM-II\P30 LGBM\lightgbm.py" is it your file or a part of lightgbm module?
If it is your file, did you check for "ls" command availability and "../input" directory availability? Probably, you import lightgbm module not from Anaconda but rather from this location D:\RI\0Teaching Materials\QTDM-II\P30 LGBM\.

Comment: Try updating conda first `conda update -c conda-forge conda` and then 
`conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`. There were similar issues with this package: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7891. If the issue persists, you should open a `New Issue` at https://github.com/conda-forge/lightgbm-feedstock/issues

Comment: When I tried with `conda install -c conda-forge lightgbm`, I also had errors. But when I did `conda install lightgbm`, it was installed successfully.

Comment: By the way could you post the stack trace you got from Ubuntu, It can not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have D:\RI\0Teaching Materials\QTDM-II\P30 LGBM\ in your PYTHONPATH, you can check it in the notebook by:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

or on commandline

```
echo %PYTHONPATH%
```

The directory will be in the python path if you start the notebook in that directory.
Because you have that directory in the python path, when you try to import module lightgbm, python is finding lightgbm.py file and then imports it, and in that file you have code that is shelling out to 'ls ../input' and you do not have 'ls' on Windows, hence the error. Second possibility is that the ls command can not see ../input because file does not exist. this does not mater, issue is still that import statement is finding lightgbm.py file before it finds the lightgbm module that you have installed with conda and actually want to import. (Hacky fix would be to rename lightgbm.py to something else)

Fix your PYTHONPATH, you can unset it following: https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10

Comment: Yes, lightgbm.py is in my path and it is refering to a gbm solution (not part of lightgbm module). The name should not have been exactly 'lightgbm'. I should check the trace more carefully.  Thanks VirtualVDX, Tomasz and amanb.

Comment: It has happend to me few times. :)

Comment: @RegiMathew could you release the bounty now that you have accepted the answer ?